# Hibernate Exception during Session.persist when String field contains question marks

Tags: java, hibernate, session

When I call Session.persist passing an entity object that has a String property with multiple question marks, I get the exception shown below.

The exception seems to occur because hibernate uses question marks as value placeholders in prepared statements.

Would anyone know a work around for this issue?

Here's the string representation of the object that triggers the exception:

> WcmsPart [mpn=04EAC2 ??? 16-001, cpn=null, description=PRIMER
>   POLYURETHANE PAINT, quantity=1, ...]

And below is the exception.  Appreciate your suggestions

```
Exception: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

Stack Trace:
org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:129)
org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:62)
org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3124)
org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3581)
org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:104)
org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:465)
org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeInserts(ActionQueue.java:337)
org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:176)
org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:216)
org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:334)
org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:289)
org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:195)
org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:126)
org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
```

Comment: please attache the query that your are invoking.. with all params set

Comment: I'm simply calling `session.persist(wcmsPart);`

Answer (score 0):

The question mark is supposed to be a parameter, in Hibernate/SQL. So you need to escape it, before persisting your data

Comment: A replaceAll on the string would help